# How to keep countUp.js scroll event from firing on every scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, eventhandler, debouncing

I have a page with four number elements that should increment using CountUp.js when each is scrolled into view. However, all four elements return to zero and then increment back to their assigned data-value on every scroll.

I'm currently using the .forEach method to go through all the elements (.counter) that have the data-value attribute that CountUp is looking for.

How can I make it so CountUp only fires once for the elements as they are scrolled into view?

I apologize in advance if this has been covered already, but I've read through many Stack Overflow articles and haven't been able to solve this.

I've tried setting a flag:

```
let hasFired = false;
```

And then having this flag updated in the .forEach statement.

```
const options = {
    useEasing: true,
    useGrouping: true,
    separator: ',',
    decimal: '.',
};

const number = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
let hasFired = false;

function countStart() {
    number.forEach(function(item) {
            const countValue = item.getAttribute('data-value');
            const countUP = new CountUp(item, 0, countValue, 0, 2, options);
            if (!countUP.error) {
                    countUP.start();
            }
    });
}

function scrollTrigger() {
    number.forEach(function(item) {
            const boxPosition = item.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            const boxPositionPercent = (boxPosition / window.innerHeight) * 100;
            if (boxPositionPercent <= 100 && hasFired === false) {
                    countStart();
                    hasFired = true;
            } else {
                    console.log('else fired');
            }
    });
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollTrigger);
```

Even with the hasFired flag being updated, every CountUp action is fired when any scrolling occurs.

This is what the HTML looks like:

```
The HTML of my page is like this:

<main id="ar-contain">
    <div class="ar-group">
        <div class="ar-narrow">
            <div class="ar-group__box">
                <h2 class="counter">0</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: I don't know anything about countUp.js, but I've answered a similar question a few months ago here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56999795/how-detect-which-child-element-is-visible-after-scrolling-the-parent-div/57000720#57000720 It's a pure JS solution that I think might be useful for you :)

Comment: @icecub Thanks for your response! I can't get `getVisibleHeight()` to run, however. I've added my HTML to my original post, if that helps. 

These are the variables I am using in your code from the other post:
`const container = document.getElementById('ar-contain');`
 `const counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');`

Comment: That's not exactly how it works. The container should be the element containing the elements that increase / decrease the counter when scrolled into view. The counter itself should be outside of that container. I mean, it can be inside just fine, but the counter would scroll out of the users view if you do that.